# How to get data attribute from clicked element after successfull dragging action in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, custom-data-attribute

I have a dragging and dropping interface which does the following action:
You drag an Item into another section of a page. This item has a data attribute. But when i finish the dragging Process it gives me an undefined var. Here is my source code to understand it a little bit better.

My HTML:
´

```
                <div id="grid" class="grid clearfix">
                    <div class="grid__item" id="apfel" data-name="Äpfel"><img src="img/produkte/obst/apfel.jpg" width="100%"></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="banane" data-name="Bananen"><img src="img/produkte/obst/banane.jpg" width="100%"></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="avocado" data-name="Avocado"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="apfel" data-name="Äpfel"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="apfel" data-name="Äpfel"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="birne" data-name="Birnen"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="orange" data-name="Orangen"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="nektariene" data-name="Nektarienen"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="pampelmuse" data-name="Pampelmusen"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="zitrone" data-name="Zitronen"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="wintraubehell" data-name="Weintrauben hell"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="weintraubedunkel" data-name="Weintrauben rot"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="kiwi" data-name="Kiwi"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="papaya" data-name="Papaya"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="mongo"data-name="Mango"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" id="drachenfrucht" data-name="Drachenfrucht"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <div id="drop-area" class="drop-area">
            <div>
                <div class="drop-area__item"><div class="dummy"></div></div>
                <div class="drop-area__item"><div class="dummy"></div></div>
                <div class="drop-area__item"><div class="dummy"></div></div>
                <div class="drop-area__item"><div class="dummy"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-overlay"></div>
```

and my script part:
´

```
(function() {
                var body = document.body,
                    dropArea = document.getElementById( 'drop-area' ),
                    droppableArr = [], dropAreaTimeout;

                // initialize droppables
                [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#drop-area .drop-area__item' )).forEach( function( el ) {
                    droppableArr.push( new Droppable( el, {
                        onDrop : function( instance, draggableEl ) {
                            // show checkmark inside the droppabe element
                            classie.add( instance.el, 'drop-feedback' );
                            clearTimeout( instance.checkmarkTimeout );
                            instance.checkmarkTimeout = setTimeout( function() { 
                                classie.remove( instance.el, 'drop-feedback' );
                            }, 800 );
                            // ...
                        }
                    } ) );
                } );

                // initialize draggable(s)
                [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll( '#grid .grid__item' )).forEach( function( el ) {
                    new Draggable( el, droppableArr, {
                        draggabilly : { containment: document.body },
                        onStart : function() {
                            // add class 'drag-active' to body
                            classie.add( body, 'drag-active' );
                            // clear timeout: dropAreaTimeout (toggle drop area)
                            clearTimeout( dropAreaTimeout );
                            // show dropArea
                            classie.add( dropArea, 'show' );

                        },
                        onEnd : function( wasDropped ) {
                            var afterDropFn = function() {
                                // hide dropArea
                                classie.remove( dropArea, 'show' );
                                // remove class 'drag-active' from body
                                classie.remove( body, 'drag-active' );


                            };

                            if( !wasDropped ) {
                                afterDropFn();
                            }
                            else {
                                // after some time hide drop area and remove class 'drag-active' from body
                                clearTimeout( dropAreaTimeout );
                                dropAreaTimeout = setTimeout( afterDropFn, 400 );
                                //No Variable is getting by the script he says undefined 
                                alert($(this).attr('data-name'));

                            }
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            })();
```

Iam using Draggabilly as library.

Comment: are u kidding me ?

Comment: Can you please mention which library you're using for draggables and droppables ? Also mention that in the post.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I am using Draggabilly as library the script comes from this site cant get it modified right pls need some help would be great.

Comment: correct me if wrong. Draggabilly uses `new Draggabilly()` and not `new Draggable()`. It seems like you're using script.aculo.us. Just a suggestion: you can try jQueryUI for drag-and-drop, it's easy to use with far better support

Comment: @DeepakKumar Please Take a Look at [http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/11/11/drag-and-drop-interaction-ideas/](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/11/11/drag-and-drop-interaction-ideas/) think this would be easier is ascript from this site if u could helü me getting the data-name out would be awesome.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with your code? Can you create a jsfiddle/ some demo for this?

Comment: Yes i create a fiddle for that. i wantto get the clicked draggable divs data-attribute value after successfull drop to the specified area.

Comment: Link to the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry @DeepakKumar unable to create a fiddle demo could u take look at the site demo here pls?[Demo Link](http://tympanus.net/Development/DragDropInteractions/) U would help me a lot man if u could figure it out with me together.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out how to get the data-name attribute really simpel

```
var attrValue = $('#grid').find('.is-active').attr('data-name');
alert(attrValue );
```